# Probability: there are 8 women and 2 men. What is the probability that at least one man is present in a randomly picked group of 3 people?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I tried to solve this probability question with my own way, but it seems the answers do not match up.

> Firsty,here  is the solution in the book

1-(probability of  not  having any  men in the formed group)=>

[image]

> Here is my solution.

Firstly I found the  number of possible combinations:

[image]

Then I found the number of possibilities where at least one man is present

[image]

Then  the probability of at least one man in the group is  the number of desired outcomes divided by all possible outcomes:

[image]

But  my answer is 8/29 but in the book answer is 8/15

Comment: Can you elaborate on your "number of possibilities where at least one man is present"? Pay particular attention to explaining the case of 2 women and 1 man.

Comment: When  at least one man is present it is either two women and one man, or two man and one woman  right?,  when it is two women and  one man  = ( different possible ways of choosing one women from 8 people) multiply by ( different possible ways of choosing one  woman from 7 people) multiply by ( different possible ways of choosing  one man out of 2).

Comment: Suppose there are just 2 women and 2 men. How many ways are there to pick 3 people such that exactly one man is present? Can you explicitly list all of these cases out? How does that compare with your approach?

Comment: there are two ways

Comment: How many ways are there via your above approach? Are they the same number of ways?

Comment: No, they are not the same. I think there is a mistake in my calculation.  i  am trying to solve this using combinatorics

Comment: For both approach, list out the ways with $W_1, W_2, M_1, M_2$. That will help you identify why one of the ways is incorrect, and how to fix that mistake. Then you can go back and fix the original mistake. In particular, use the correct combinatorics tool.

Comment: I found out the mistake.  I  should have  calculated the ( number of ways  of choosing  2 women out of 8) multiplied by ( number of ways of choosing one man  out of 2). When there are  two woman and  a  man, instead of doing it separately.

Answer (score 1):

From the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution):
$$\frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{8}{2}+\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}=\frac{2\cdot28+1\cdot8}{120}=\frac{8}{15}$$

Alternatively, use the complement:
$$1-\frac{\binom{2}{0}\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}=1-\frac{1\cdot56}{120}=1-\frac{7}{15}=\frac{8}{15}$$